# Withdrew Bitcoin from Binance to someone's wallet. They said they never received it

Tags: transactions, blockchain, wallet

I sent 0.3061 BTC from Binance 4 days ago to a wallet but the recipient said they never got anything. The address is bc1qsx2w6u4vgwmadp964s66yu6nuu85cdg58a9kpf. Every blockchain site says the transaction is confirmed but they said nothing came. I've sent many times to this person in the past and never had an issue until now. They are not a scammer. This was, however the FIRST instance where I withdrew directly into the person's wallet instead of first sending it to my hot wallet(coinbase) and then sending it to their wallet. I fear that that one step I skipped caused this problem and I just want to know if there's anything we can do.

Answer (score 1):

Looking this up, I can see that address `bc1qsx2w6u4vgwmadp964s66yu6nuu85cdg58a9kpf` was paid 0.3061 BTC in transaction `a05ac2bc83db0f51433b9b96220bc7bc7e7ea75a09d6487282f6c3877d7106cf`.

5 blocks later, these funds were then sent to `3KeaXjhEfHrNdcQWp8ZyFgyzD7fQ7QoXMt`, etc.

So there is no doubt the payment was made. Considering the funds have already been moved, we can assume the issue is not the recipient's wallet not being properly sync'd with the network. The most obvious remaining possibility is that they are being dishonest.

> This was, however the FIRST instance where I withdrew directly into the person's wallet instead of first sending it to my hot wallet(coinbase) and then sending it to their wallet. I fear that that one step I skipped caused this problem and I just want to know if there's anything we can do.

This makes no difference. The transaction was confirmed, the payment was sent. There was no issue there.